# Elasticsearch _mapping API is not telling me which fields are not analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to stop elasticsearch from analyzing some fields in my documents.
I posted this mapping:

```
{
  "properties" : {
     "f1" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "type" : "string"
     },
     "f2" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "type" : "string"
     },
     "f3" : {
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all" : false,
        "type" : "string"
     }
  }
}
```

Then I ping the mapping endpoint and it doesn't tell me if those fields
are analyzed or not:

```
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "mytype" : {
        "properties" : {
          "f1" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "include_in_all" : false
          },
          "f2" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "include_in_all" : false
          },
          "f3" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "include_in_all" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the examples I have seen querying _mapping API seems to tell what fields are analyzed or not.

Comment: In ES 5, the `keyword` type is equivalent to what used to be a `not_analyzed` `string` in previous ES versions.

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch 5.0 and later there's a new way of separating analyzed and non-analyzed content:

- [Strings are dead, long live strings!](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)
- [Keyword datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

But, to summarize:

- keyword is not analyzed
- text is analyzed

and the index property that had 3 values: "no","analyzed","not-analyzed" is now simplified to just "yes" and "no"